# How to revert a "gzip -r folder/" command?

Tags: gzip

I accidentally compressed all the files using the Gzip method which compresses all the files (not directories) individually, replacing the uncompressed files with the .gz compressed files.

How can I revert the operation I just did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there aren't any files you want to remain `gzip'd`, use `gzip -dr folder/`

Comment: Or just `gunzip -r folder`